# Java arraylist throwing dice

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm new to Java and i'm trying to make a arraylist.

I made a small program that asks the user for a amount of dices to roll :

```
    System.out.println("How many dices do you want to throw?");
    int diceAmount = input.nextInt();
```

then I made a loop to print the dices but I can't get it to make the amount of dices to be random. I have to count the total dices with the random results also:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= diceAmount; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "-");
```

Comment: I saw your comment that you want to know how to sum the numbers. So I updated the answer adding that part.

Answer (score 2):

```
Random rand = new Random();

(int i = 1; i <= diceAmount; i++) {
   // roll the dice once
  int roll1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
  System.out.print(i + "-" + roll1);
}
```

UPDATE:

Here is the way to sum up the numbers. So let's say you roll 2 dice every time.

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    // roll the dice once
    int roll1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    int roll2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    sum = roll1 + roll2;
    System.out.println("You got " + sum + ". Not bad!");
```

Answer (score 1):

For each die roll you want a random number (presumably 1-6, if its a traditional die). So your loop is correct, but the body of the loop needs fixing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < diceAmount; i++){ //repeats diceAmount times
   //Do loop stuff. 
}
```

To get a random number, start with `Math.random()`. This will return a random `double` in the range `[0 .. 1)`. This means that `0` is a valid return, but `1` is not. From there we want to stretch the range to go up to 6.

```
Math.random() * 6
```

Returns a random double in the range `[0 ..6)`. We need integers, not doubles, so let's cast that.

```
(int)(Math.random() * 6)
```

Returns a random *int* in the range `[0 .. 6)` -> `[0 .. 5]`. From there, just add 1.

```
(int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1
```

Will return a random int in the range `[1 .. 6]`, which is precisely your goal. So all together:

```
for(int i = 0; i < diceAmount; i++){
    int dieRoll = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    System.out.println(dieRoll);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works great, but how do I count all the dices and if a dice is below 2 I roll that dice again

Comment: You'll have to use an `if` statement to check if `dieRoll < 2`, and perhaps loop over that. Give it a shot, and if you're having trouble post another question.

Comment: But lets say a dice is below 2, how do I roll that dice and not all the dices? I think I need to use array list?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, just call `dieRoll = ...` again, that'll basically re-roll it.

Comment: and how do I sum all the dices?

Comment: How do I sum all the thrown dices?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.random()` to randomise your number of dice. There are lots of overloaded version of `random()` method. Read about Java.Math in Oracle documentation.

Comment: How do I create the amount of random dices the user inputs?
Like the user inputs 5, then I need to print 5 random numbers